# jquery .off() vs pointer-events: none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button, upon clicking on which some logic is executed in jquery. After some other events I want the click on button to stop doing anything. Which is better to use `$(".myBtn").off(click.mynamespace)` or `$(".myBtn").css("pointer-events", none);`?

I think with pointer events none it literally disables any click, focus and hover action. And with jquery off it simply stops executing previously assinged `.click()` events.

Comment: Use `off()` for full browser support.

Comment: `off()` is better in your case. `pointer-events:none` will basically make the element stop responding to your cursor at a much deeper level than just javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a third option: set the `disabled` attribute on your button element. In addition to supressing mouse and click events, the default styling will change to appear grey, informing the user that the button can't be clicked. If you later want to re-enable the button, it's simple to remove the attribute.

```
$('button').prop('disabled', true);  // disable buttons
$('button').prop('disabled', false);  // enable buttons
```

With regards to your original two suggestions:

- If the button will never be re-enabled, consider removing it entirely, don't just remove its click event listener. Conversely, don't remove the event listener if the button is likely to be re-enabled with the same action.
- Using the `pointer-events` css property in this way would be a bad hack. It's intended to let clicks "pass through" transparent elements to other controls in the background.